# Filtering values out of two dimensional data in R, comparing themselves

Tags: r, statistics, data-mining

I'm analyzing USA election data, candidates contribution, etc.  So I got raw data from internet and trying to learn some R executing some exercises in it.  This is a CSV file that I successfully loaded and analyzed with `?summary`.

I also used `?tapply` successfully, to separate candidates money contribution by state:

```
data_amt_st = tapply(data$contb_receipt_amt, data[c('cand_nm', 'contbr_st')], sum)
```

`?str` (for a small sample) tells me the format of this data:

```
> str(data_amt_st)
 num [1:3, 1:21] NA NA 451 NA NA 201 NA NA 200 NA ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ cand_nm  : chr [1:3] "Bachmann, Michele" "Obama, Barack" "Romney, Mitt"
  ..$ contbr_st: chr [1:21] "33" "46" "48" "7" ...
```

Now I need to filter out values from data_amt_st.  I need states that "Obama, Barack" had more contributions than other candidates, but don't know how to do. Something with `?subset`?

Thank you very much.

---

EDIT 1: Attending what guys told me, about making a more concrete question:  I need a list of the states where Barack Obama achieved a higher contribution level (more money) than other candidates.

---

EDIT 2: Trying to give you a reproducible example (is it correct?):

```
x = c("a", "b", "c")
y0 = c(3, 5, 1)
y1 = c(2, 1, 6)
y2 = c(4, 2, 3)
m = cbind(x, y0, y1, y2)
m
#      x   y0  y1  y2 
# [1,] "a" "3" "2" "4"
# [2,] "b" "5" "1" "2"
# [3,] "c" "1" "6" "3"
```

Now, I need to know, for what y values, `a` is higher than `b` and `c`.

Comment: In addition, it would be helpful if you told us _exactly_ what you are trying to achieve. "I need to filter out values from data_amt_st" is unclear. By what criteria do you want to filter?

Comment: Ah, Josh O'Brien, now I see what you meant when you told me "reproducible example" :-) Thanks.

Comment: your matrix would make more sense as `m <- data.frame(y0,y1,y2); rownames(m) <- x`; combining characters and numerics in a matrix gets them all coerced to matrices

Comment: Thanks for adding the reproducible example. You can directly convert your matrix to the better data format Ben Bolker suggested by doing `df <- as.data.frame(m[,2:4], row.names=m[,1])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
## max by column (MARGIN=2)
max_amt <- apply(data_amt_st,MARGIN=2,max,na.rm=TRUE)  
data_amt_st[,max_amt==data_amt_st["Obama",]]
```

?
(Not sure how this will work with `NA` values in the Obama row: using `dput` to give us a reproducible example ( http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ) would be useful ...)

```
x <- letters[1:3]
y0 <- c(3, 5, 1)
y1 <- c(2, 1, 6)
y2 <- c(4, 2, 3)
m <- data.frame(y0, y1, y2)
rownames(m) <- x
maxvals <- apply(m,2,max,na.rm=TRUE)
which(m["a",]==maxvals)  ## or
names(m)[m["a",]==maxvals]
```

Comment: Might be a good spot for `which.max()`, as in `names(m)[apply(m, 2, which.max)==1]`